# Implicit authorization - AAD

Tags: vba, vb.net, azure, authentication

I am trying to request a token using an html code (as below), but you are asking to log in to my account.
I needed to do an implicit authentication, I have already configured azure, but the login screen still appears.
Whats wrong
[Imagem da configuração do Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk8bw.png)

The manifest is as follows
...
...
"keyCredentials": [],
"knownClientApplications": [],
"logoUrl": null,
"logoutUrl": null,
"name": "Zurich - Facilite",
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2Permissions": [],
"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
"optionalClaims": null,
"orgRestrictions": [],
...
...

The code I am using to authorize

```
tokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" & id_teant & "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?"
tokenUri = tokenUri & "client_id=" & id_client
tokenUri = tokenUri & "&response_type=id_token" ' code"
tokenUri = tokenUri & "&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"
tokenUri = tokenUri & "&response_mode=query"
tokenUri = tokenUri & "&scope=openid profile https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send offline_access User.Read User.Read.All"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-the-sign-in-request) about implicit grant flow. You could see this in the **Tip**.

> After signing in, your browser should be redirected to your redirect
> uri with an id_token in the address bar.

The login screen is used to sign in with your account, and then it will return the token. If you want to get both id_token and access_token, set `response_type` with `id_token token`.

If you want to get the token without users, try [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). The OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow permits a web service (confidential client) to use its own credentials, instead of impersonating a user, to authenticate when calling another web service.

Comment: Good Morning
Sorry for my ignorance, but I tried and I was unsuccessful, I read the document several times and I was unable to configure Azure and I couldn't even create the token.
Would you happen to have an example of how to request the token without a user and a summary of how to set up Azure?
Thank you very much

Comment: Try with client credentials flow and request the URL, it will response the access token that you want to 
obtain, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token).